# Continuous delivery and database schema changes with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relational-database, database-schema, continuous-deployment

We want to progress towards being able to do continuous delivery of of our application into production.  We currently deploy to azure and use table/blob storage and have a azure sql database, which we access with the entity.

As the database schema changes we want to be able to automatically apply the schema changes to the production database, but as this will happen whilst the application is live and the code changes are being deployed to many nodes at the same time we are not sure what the correct approach is.

After some reading it seems (and this makes sense) that the application needs to be tolerant of the 2 different database schema versions, so that it doesn't matter if its an old version of the code or a new version of the code which sees the database, however I'm not sure what the best way to approach handling this in the application is, using the entity framework.

Should we have versioned instances of the EF generated classes in the code which know how to access a specific version of the schema?  What happens when the schema is updated and an old version of the code is running against the database?

Our entity framework classes are mapped to views in specific schemas in the db and nothing is mapped to the underlying tables, so potentially this could allow us to create v1 views which the old code uses and v2 views which the new code uses, but maintaining this feels like it would be a bit of a nightmare (its already enough of a pain simply maintaining the EF mappings to views rather than tables)

So what are best practices in this area?  What do others do to solve this problem?

Comment: you may find this useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn481501

Comment: Hey, were able to achive continuous deployment with Entity framework. We are using database first approach and trying to achive the same backwards compatibility. I would really appreciate if you can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether you use EF or not, maintaining the code's ability to work with 2 consecutive versions of the database is a good (and perhaps the only viable) approach here.

Here are some ways we handle specific types of migrations:

- When adding a column, we can typically just add the column (with a default constraint if non-nullable) and not worry about the code. EF will never issue a "SELECT *", so it will be able to continue to function properly while ignoring the new column. Similarly, adding a table is easy.
- When removing a column or table, simply keep that column around 1 version longer than you would have otherwise.
- For more complex migrations (e. g. completely changing the structure for a table or segment of the data model), deploy the new model alongside backwards-compatibility views (or tables with triggers to keep them in-sync), which will live as long as does the code that references them. As you say, this can a lot of work depending on the complexity of the migration, but it sounds like you are already well-positioned to do this because your EF entities point to views anyway. On the other hand, the benefit of this work is that you have more time to do the code migration. If you have a large codebase, this could be really beneficial in allowing you to migrate the data model to fit the needs of new features while still supporting old features without major code changes.

As a side-note, the difficulty of data migration often makes us push developing a finalized data model as far back as possible in the development schedule. With EF, you can write and test a lot of code before the data model is finalized (we use code-first to generate a sample SQLExpress database in a unit tests, even though our production database is not maintained by code-first). That way, we make fewer incremental changes to the production data model once a new feature is released.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  The implication in your answer is effectively that you have a 'current' and 'new' schema that are supported and that changes in the 'current' can be dropped one 'new' is in use everywhere.  But what if you are rolling back changes to a previous version, or if you have multiple versions being deployed across machines simultaneously?  Is there are technique for handling that? And how are the update scripts generated, managed and applied?

Comment: @SamHolder: in our architecture, we don't support automatically rolling back the database to previous versions (other than restoring from a backup) as this would require additional work for little benefit in our case. Thus, each database is either on version N or version N + 1, with the applications that consume them supporting both versions. Nothing gets upgraded to N + 2 until everything is on N + 1. We write our upgrade scripts manually, since our schema is sufficiently complex that automated tools won't do the trick. However, we have some in-house stored procs to simplify common tasks.